# Find shape picture by file name

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word, openxml

I have this `xml` structure in my `dotx` file:

[image]

I need to access that picture in `VBA Word API` by its name.
I can do following:

```sh
$Picture = $ActiveDocument.Shapes(1) 
Write-Host $Picture.Name #Will return "Image"
```

But this only returns the first file name "Image". Is there a way to get the inside file name "File Name.gif"?

I found similar problem [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14ce5e97-d1aa-49b4-890a-68180049ca35/how-do-i-access-a-picture-filename-in-a-word-doc?forum=isvvba), but without answer.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Using VBA you can only access the shape name, not the original file name of the embedded image. To get that you would need to read it from the XML.

Comment: To help people help you, post the full XML code.

Comment: The original file name is only retained for _linked_ pictures, not embedded ones.